# Getting errors when starting tomcat

Tags: spring, mybatis

My project is a dynamic web project,not maven project.
It gets errors when startting tomcat:

```
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/springmvc]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5412)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
```

I think it's caused by web.xml,codes below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
version="3.0">  
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>  
<context-param>  
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
    <param-value>file:WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-mybatis.xml</param-value>  
</context-param>  

<!-- Spring MVC servlet -->  
<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
        <param-value>file:WebContent/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
<listener>  
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
</listener>  
<listener>  
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.IntrospectorCleanupListener</listener-class>  
</listener>
<filter>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>  
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>  
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
</filter>  
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

I have googled before,most of them dont configure context-param and servlet,but I have configured them.And I have added jar files in lib.
This is my file structure:

```
-WEB-INF
--spring-mvc.xml
--spring-mybatis.xml
--web.xml
```

Are there someting wrongs with the contextConfigLocation?I also tried /WEB-INF/spring-mybatis.xml,but it not worked.

Comment: A classnotfounderror is caused by a missing class on your application classpath. Check on WEB-INF/lib if all needed jars are there.

Comment: @JorgeCampos In my project WebApplicationContext is in spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar,I can find it in my WEB-INF/lib and build path.

Comment: You can try if this works `<param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc.xml</param-value>`

Comment: Finally,I create a new project and copy all files to it,it runs.. I guess the problem is that I right-click on lib folder and set the folder as source folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Recommended Options**

1. Use Maven/Gradle project to build your project in your IDE and let them to take care of your dependencies.
2. When you are using spring framework it is always recommended to use [Bill of Materials](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/anthavio/maven/spring-framework-bom/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-4.1.4.RELEASE.pom) to avoid ClassNotFound exception.
3. [Spring-boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) is very popular, if you wish you can choose that option too to avoid XML configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mission some jar to be added please make sure that you have below jars added... According to spring-webmvc 3.1.2 need following jar: I have given the same answer earlier so refer the below jar

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar
```